# Django Rest Framework: Set Permissions for function view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

The default permissions requires token authentication. I have a function based view that has the `api_view` decorator. How can I explicitly set its permissions to not require authentication and csrf exempt?

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    ....
```

Comment: have you tried to set `AllowAny`  in the permission_classes decorator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [permission_classes](http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/permissions#permissions) decorator like this:

```
  @api_view(['GET'])
  @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
  def activate(request, uidb64, token):
....
```

Comment: Ah, that's the decorator I needed.